# What is the correct way to setup mocking for this unit test involving named Unity resources?

Tags: c#, unity-container, moq, mstest, automoq

I am wanting to write up a unit test that checks that a specific Unity IoC object was instantiated.

For example, here is the class I am testing.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System.Threading;

namespace Client.Engine
{
    public sealed class Uploader : IUploader
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

        public Uploader(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public void PerformUpload(CancellationToken token, int batchSize)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            _container.Resolve<IUploadModule>("Clients").Upload(token, batchSize);

            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            _container.Resolve<IUploadModule>("Patients").Upload(token, batchSize);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the unit tests I set up

```
[TestClass()]
public class UploadClientsTests : UploadModuleTestsBase
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public override void UploaderRegrestrationTest()
    {
        PerformRegistrationTest("Clients");
    }
}

[TestClass()]
public class UploadPatientsTests : UploadModuleTestsBase
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public override void UploaderRegrestrationTest()
    {
        PerformUpladerRegistrationTest("Patients");
    }
}

public class UploadPatientsTests : UploadModuleTestsBase
{
    protected static void PerformUpladerRegistrationTest(string moduleName)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        var mocker = new AutoMoqer(container);
        var random = new Random();
        int batchSize = random.Next(int.MaxValue);
        var token = new CancellationToken();

        var uploadModuleMock = new Mock<IUploadModule>();
        uploadModuleMock.Setup(module => module.Upload(token, batchSize)).Verifiable();

        container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IUploadModule), moduleName, uploadModuleMock.Object, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IUploadModule), Mock.Of<IUploadModule>());
        var uploader = mocker.Resolve<Uploader>();
        uploader.PerformUpload(token, batchSize);

        uploadModuleMock.Verify();
    }
}
```

The problem I run in to is Unity 2.0 does not fall back to the default instance if a named type is not available. So if I comment out the `_container.Resolve<IUploadModule>("Patients")` line the clients test works perfectly, and if I comment out  `_container.Resolve<IUploadModule>("Clients")` the patients test works perfectly, I just don't know how to make it so both can co-exist.

---

EDIT: In normal operation I am restringing the two objects like this.

```
public static Bootstrap(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<IUploadModule, UploadClients>("Clients", new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IUploadModule, UploadPatients>("Patients", new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not actually just mock `IUnityContainer` directly, instead of using a real UnityContainer?

From the point of view of unit testing the `PerformUpload` method you should only assert that indeed both `Resolve<>` and `Upload` methods are called and with the corresponding parameters. Not the actual internals of how Unity resolves.

In fact you could even remove the dependency on the `IUnityContainer` and have your constructor receive a factory method instead, that you can register in Unity.
I tend to avoid such dependencies, and declare the factory directly as `Func<string, IUploadModule>`.

The following example is untested but something like the following may work:

```
container.RegisterType<Func<string, IUploadModule>>(new InjectionFactory(c => 
    new Func<string, IUploadModule>(name => 
        c.Resolve<IUploadModule>(name)
        )
    )
);
```

This is an additional registration. You would also have to have your uploaders registered just as you have them now.

With that registered, you can have your constructor use `Func<string, IUploadModule>` as a parameter:

```
public Uploader(Func<string, IUploadModule> factory)
{
    _factory = factory;
}
```

And invoke it in the following manner to get your uploader:

```
_factory("Patients");
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, and if I did not get a Unity solution (I am new to Unity so I did not know if there is a setting or function I could call to change how it handles unmapped named resolvers) that is what I am going to do. However I was hoping to have a more general solution for when I have a more complicated classes and similar situations.

Comment: Could you show a example of the Factory solution and how you would register the two classes outside of a Unit-Test scenario? I have updated my question showing how I currently have them registered. EDIT: What you said makes a lot more sense now with a example, thanks! I will give this a try on Monday!

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know if it doesn't work and we'll have a second go at it.

Comment: Other than a extra `;` that was not needed it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how everything is designed in your application, IMO I think your `Uploader` class should be restructured a bit.  The `PerformUpload` method has dependencies to `IUploadModule` but instead of taking them in as dependencies as you should for IoC, you're resolving them manually in `Uploader`.  If you had a new `IUploadModule`, you would have to change your `PerformUpload` method, which kind of defeats the purpose of doing IoC.

My suggestion is something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System.Threading;

namespace Client.Engine
{
    public sealed class Uploader : IUploader
    {
        public Uploader()
        {
        }

        public void PerformUpload(IUploadModule uploadModule, CancellationToken token, int batchSize)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            uploadModule.Upload(token, batchSize);
        }
    }
}
```

This will also simplify your unit test.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void PerformUpladerRegistrationTest()
{
    var random = new Random();
    int batchSize = random.Next(int.MaxValue);
    var token = new CancellationToken();

    var uploadModuleMock = new Mock<IUploadModule>();
    uploadModuleMock.Setup(module => module.Upload(token, batchSize)).Verifiable();

    uploader.PerformUpload(uploadModuleMock.Object, token, batchSize);

    uploadModuleMock.Verify();
}
```

Comment: The reason for the structuring is depending on where the project is deployed I may have a different implementation of each individual module but the total sets of modules would stay the same. A more "propper" IoC pattern would of me doing `public Uploader(IClientUploadModule clientUploadModule, IPatientUploadModule patientUploadModule, ...)` The reason I did not do it that way is in the real project I have about 15 more modules that would go in to the `...`. The unit test I was writing is the test to verify a module is set up to called from one of the 17 known entry points.